# Latest updates on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: updates, update-manager

Since I upgraded to ubuntu 14.10 , I didn't received any update.
When I tape :
sudo apt-get update

It says that my system is up-to-date

When was the last time you received an update on the ubuntu 14.10 ?

Thanks

Comment: You only get updates when there actually *are* updates. Updates exist because package maintainers drop bug fixes and distro maintainers stage them. It's the winter Holiday season in much of the world, so the people who would be doing those things may simply be otherwise occupied. Is there some update that you *know* you should be getting?

Comment: I selected "install pre-release updates" and I received some updates now

Comment: Is it safe to install them ?

Comment: Well, they're "pre-release" updates because the maintainers haven't completed testing them. Whether they're safe depends on what they are. If you're talking about updates to applications, they probably can't do much damage. Updates to important system software could be risky if they prevent you from booting or using the system.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not received an update for 3 days, you should be sure to run both `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` together, as one gets new package versions, and one actually installs the updates.

I generally get updates at least every week, if you don't, try switching your mirror back to the main ubuntu repository in your software and sources.

Comment: I already tried these two solutions , but I still not receive anything !

Comment: When is the last time you received an update?

Comment: 22-12-2014, the same day when I upgraded to ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I'd say wait another month, and if you still never get any updates then there is a serious problem.

Comment: Why a month exactly ?

Comment: @MarwenDoukh Because I'm fairly certain that there will be an update by then. Otherwise it's just a rough timeframe. Feel free to contact me then, I'll be glad to help.